# What is the ratio of cosmic ray energy to dark matter energy in our solar system?

Tags: dark-matter, cosmic-rays

In any cubic meter of space in our solar system there is predicted to be some amount of dark matter. Also in a cubic meter of space is a known average amount of cosmic ray energy. What is the ratio of cosmic ray energy to dark matter energy in our solar system? I'm curious if they are on the same order of magnitude or far from it.

Comment: How would you define "dark matter energy"? $E=\text{dark matter mass}\times c^2$?

Comment: Yes I suppose .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integrated local interstellar cosmic ray energy density is claimed by [Webber (1998)](http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/506/1/329/fulltext/37305.text.html) to be about 1.8 ev/cm$^3$. The energy density of dark matter (mostly rest mass energy) in the solar system is thought to be around $0.43\pm0.1$ GeV/cm$^{3}$ ([Salucci et al. 2010](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3101)).

Both numbers likely have quite big error bars, but as you can see, there is an 8-9 orders of magnitude difference.